# Is there any function in Karate Gatling to avoid duplicate API endpoint if {id} is random param in Gatling report

Tags: api, automation, karate

** The challenge is here- In My Karate Gatling report one of the API si printed multiple times since the API endpoint having {id} as in QueryParam which is random**

** I have read out the karateProtocol() but it's not resolving my purpose**

- I have attached the screen capture to get it understand easily*[Screnn shot from my Gatling report where one API printed multiple times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGIXf.png)

Comment: maybe you did not set the `karateProtocol()` correctly: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#karateprotocol - it works for other teams. so if you are still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue